# Split vector in R every time vector element changes

Tags: r, split

I need to split a vector of repeated groups of elements every time the element value changes. For example:

```
test_vector <- c("string1", "string1", "string1", "string2", 
  "string2", "string1", "string1", "string3")
```

must become:

```
$`1`
[1] "string1" "string1" "string1"

$`2`
[1] "string2" "string2"

$`3`
[1] "string1" "string1"

$`4`
[1] "string3"
```

If I try `split(test_vector, test_vector)` I get the wrong output:

```
$string1
[1] "string1" "string1" "string1" "string1" "string1"

$string2
[1] "string2" "string2"

$string3
[1] "string3"
```

I wrote some code which achieves this but it seems unnecessarily long and I feel like I'm missing something out there that's much simpler:

```
# find indices where splitting will occur:
split_points <- rep(F, length(test_vector))
for (i in 1:length(test_vector)) {
  if (i != 1) {
    if (test_vector[i] != test_vector[i-1]) {
      split_points[i] <- T
    }
  }
}
split_points <- c(1, which(split_points))

# create split vector:
split_code <- rep(1, length(test_vector))
for ( j in 1:length(split_points) ) {

  if (j!=length(split_points)) {
    split_code[
      split_points[j]:(split_points[j+1]-1)
    ] <- j
  } else {
    split_code[
      split_points[j]:length(test_vector)
    ] <- j
  }

}

split_result <- split(test_vector, split_code)
$`1`
[1] "string1" "string1" "string1"

$`2`
[1] "string2" "string2"

$`3`
[1] "string1" "string1"

$`4`
[1] "string3"
```

If anyone could help me find a simpler solution this would be much appreciated!

Comment: try `split(v1, rleid(v1))` or in base r `with(rle(v1), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, love the simplicity of the rleid one

Comment: Sorry I am quite new and don't know how to do that, can you let me know how?

Comment: Ah apologies, I didn't see your answer below in addition to the comment

Comment: it's okay. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `rle` to get the run-length-encoding of the vector

```
grp <- with(rle(test_vector), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
```

Use that to `split` the `vector`

```
split(test_vector, grp)
```

---

With `data.table`, `rleid` gives the id based on the difference between adjacent elements

```
library(data.table)
split(test_vector, rleid(test_vector))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f = cumsum(c(TRUE, test_vector[-length(test_vector)] != test_vector[-1]))
split(test_vector, f)
```

OR

```
with(rle(test_vector), Map(rep, values, lengths))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option is to use `findInterval` + `cumsum` + `rle`, i.e.,

```
res <- split(test_vector,
             findInterval(seq_along(test_vector),
                          cumsum(rle(test_vector)$lengths),
                          left.open = TRUE))
```

such that

```
> res
$`1`
[1] "string1" "string1" "string1"

$`2`
[1] "string2" "string2"

$`3`
[1] "string1" "string1"

$`4`
[1] "string3"
```