# using time intervals to populate a new column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(Condition = rep(c(1,2,3), each = 10),
                        Time = rep(c(1,3,7,9,16,18,25,28,29,30), times = 3))
```

I want to divide the total length of `Time` (e.g., 30) by 'x' (e.g., x = 3). Then, I want to use the quotient (e.g., 10) as an interval to add a new variable `Trial`, such that my new dataframe looks like this:

```
     Condition Time Trial
1          1    1     A
2          1    3     A
3          1    7     A
4          1    9     A
5          1   16     B
6          1   18     B
7          1   25     C
8          1   28     C
9          1   29     C
10         1   30     C
11         2    1     A
12         2    3     A
13         2    7     A
14         2    9     A
15         2   16     B
... and so on
```

As you can see, every 10 seconds per Condition, Trial is populated with a unique identifying value (e.g., "A").

In my real data set, I can specify 'x' but the `Time` varies by `Condition`.

Thanks!

Reproducible dataset for @ktiu

```
dataframe <- data.frame(Condition = rep(c(1,2,3), each = 5, times = 2),
                        Time = sort(sample(1:60, 30)))
```

Comment: How do you determine the total "length" of `Time`?  Do you mean the `length()` of the `Time` _column_ itself, which is simply the number of rows in the `data.frame`?  Or do you mean the span between the earliest and the latest time: `max(Time) - min(Time)`?  Or do you mean the span from 0 (the earliest _possible_ value in the domain of `Time`) to the latest time: `max(Time) - 0`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying question. I mean length of Time as the span between the earliest and the latest time: max(Time) - min(Time) per Condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be my approach:

```
library(dplyr)

dataframe %>%
  group_by(Condition) %>%
  mutate(Trial = LETTERS[cut(Time, 3, labels = F)])
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 30 x 3
# Groups:   Condition [3]
   Condition  Time Trial
       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1         1     1 A    
 2         1     3 A    
 3         1     7 A    
 4         1     9 A    
 5         1    16 B    
 6         1    18 B    
 7         1    25 C    
 8         1    28 C    
 9         1    29 C    
10         1    30 C    
# … with 20 more rows
```

If `Condition` is recycled (as suggested in comments) we can implement [@akrun's strategy from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60608723/split-vector-in-r-every-time-vector-element-changes) to do

```
dataframe %>%
  mutate(condition_seq = with(rle(dataframe$Condition),
                              rep(seq_along(values), lengths))) %>%
  group_by(condition_seq) %>%
  mutate(Trial = LETTERS[cut(Time, 3, labels = F)]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-condition_seq)
```

Data used:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(Condition = rep(c(1,2,3), each = 10), Time = rep(c(1,3,7,9,16,18,25,28,29,30), times = 3))
```

Comment: this is an excellent solution for the data frame that I've provided. Is there a way to make it work with time values that do not reset per Condition, but instead steadily increase per row?

Comment: Can you specify the desired behavior a little more? My solution should `cut()` the `Time` values in each `Condition`, no matter if they reset or not.

Comment: I have a data frame with many observations. The two variables of interest are `Time` and `Condition`. Time is represented not by whole number integers but by 0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.53, etc that steadily increase per row. There Condition sequences (e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) repeat every ~700 seconds of Time. Your code works beautifully with the dataframe I've provided above, but not for mine for some reason.

Comment: What happens instead is that the `Trial` cuts across the whole dataset, such that for x = 3, A appears once for 1/3 of the dataset, B appears 1/3 and C appears 1/3. I think the issue may be that Condition is not getting grouped

Comment: I tried changing time to consecutive numbers and I cannot confirm the issue: grouping and cutting works as expected. If you can provide data that lets me reproduce the issue I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: Thanks ktiu. I've placed a reproducible sample in my original post.

Comment: Of course, when I cut the dataset to a reproducible sample, your code now works. Is it because my original data has more columns besides `Time` and `Condition`? Or perhaps because it has many more observations (n ~ 50000)?

Comment: It looks like the issue only arises when I have repeating sequences (e.g., 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3) of `Condition`

Comment: I put up a better reproducible example; I might just post this as a separate question later

Comment: I included an option to handle this case in my answer.

Comment: YES! This worked!! Thank you so much. You're a lifesaver

Answer (score 2):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe %>% 
    group_by(Condition) %>%
    mutate(Trial = LETTERS[1+ (Time %/%10)]) %>%
    ungroup
```

Comment: the issue with this is that in my real data set I need the code to specify the interval because it will always vary by Condition. Thus, it will not be %/% 10 consistently

Comment: @Drew the accepted solution have similar issue as it is using `3` in `cut`

Comment: the 3 (how many times `Time` need be cut) can be specified but the length of `Time` to be cut varies by `Condition` so that cannot be specified

Answer (score 1):

We could use `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

dataframe %>% 
  mutate(Trial = case_when(Time <=10 ~ "A",
                           Time >10 & Time<=20 ~ "B",
                           Time >20 & Time<=30 ~ "C"))
```

Output:

```
   Condition  Time Trial
       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1         1     1 A    
 2         1     3 A    
 3         1     7 A    
 4         1     9 A    
 5         1    16 B    
 6         1    18 B    
 7         1    25 C    
 8         1    28 C    
 9         1    29 C    
10         1    30 C    
# ... with 20 more rows
```